# How can I find out the current route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I need to know the current route in a filter in Rails. How can I find out what it is?

I'm doing REST resources, and see no named routes.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? When you say "route" do you mean "URI"?

Comment: any thoughts on how to get it in [middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42691729/1610034).

Answer (score 218, accepted):

To find out URI:

```
current_uri = request.env['PATH_INFO']
# If you are browsing http://example.com/my/test/path, 
# then above line will yield current_uri as "/my/test/path"
```

To find out the route i.e. controller, action and params:

```
path = ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path "/your/path/here/"

# ...or newer Rails versions:
#
path = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/your/path/here')

controller = path[:controller]
action = path[:action]
# You will most certainly know that params are available in 'params' hash
```

Comment: Would you happen to know if this is the same/right way to do it in Rails 3? I'm sure it's still accessible, but I just want to be sure that I'm adhering to the latest conventions.

Comment: The current controller and action are always available in `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]`. However, outside of it, if you want to recognize the route, this API is not available anymore. It has now shifted to `ActionDispatch::Routing` and I haven't tried out the `recognize_path` on it yet.

Comment: It’s better to use `request.path` for finding the current path.

Comment: You could also call `request.env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH']` to include the possible parameters in the path, see my answer below.

Comment: current_uri = request.env['PATH_INFO'] doesn't work if trailing_slash is set in routes

Comment: @luca   The same approach does not work [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42691729/1610034), any thoughts?

Answer (score 339):

If you are trying to special case something in a view, you can use `current_page?` as in:

```
<% if current_page?(:controller => 'users', :action => 'index') %>
```

...or an action and id...

```
<% if current_page?(:controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => 1) %>
```

...or a named route...

```
<% if current_page?(users_path) %>
```

...and

```
<% if current_page?(user_path(1)) %>
```

Because `current_page?` requires both a controller and action, when I care about just the controller I make a `current_controller?` method in ApplicationController:

```
  def current_controller?(names)
    names.include?(current_controller)
  end
```

And use it like this:

```
<% if current_controller?('users') %>
```

...which also works with multiple controller names...

```
<% if current_controller?(['users', 'comments']) %>
```

Comment: Note that you can also use current_page? with named routes:

    current_page?(users_path)

Comment: Nice tothemario. I didn't know that. I'm modifying the answer.

Comment: it returns true whatever address is "/users", "/users/", "/users?smth=sdfasf".... Sometimes not so good thing in practice

Comment: `controller_name` and `action_name` are good for use in helpers and views for this sort of thing too.

Comment: Building on @Gediminas and @MattConnolly comments... `current_page?` needs at least the controller and the action. If you need just the controller, you can use `controller_name == 'users'`. I make a `current_controller?` helper that does that check and put it in ApplicationController.

Comment: In a view you can also just do <% if params[:action] == 'show' %> so you don't need the controller

Comment: How do I apply this if I have a subdomain?

Comment: I implemented this current_page logic in my application layout, and it ended up breaking the devise new confirmation page.  I had this code: if current_page?(:controller => 'pages', :action => 'about'), and the users/confirmation/new page fails with this error:  No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"devise/pages"}.  I fixed with if request.path == "/pages/about" from an answer below.

Comment: In Rails 6 (and probably as early as Rails 4 or 5), you can simply provide an active record object: `current_page?(@user)` or collection `current_page?(@users)`. Rails uses `polymorphic_path` under the hood to generate the path from the given active record object. Pretty neat!

Comment: It's true! It goes back to 1.0.0 actually. This works because ActionView will interpret `@user` as the path `\user\:id`. If the person is on the edit action `users#edit` it will return false, however, because the actual current page is `\user\:id\edit`. So it will work depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: For best practice, the `current_controller?` method would be better defined in a helper (perhaps `ApplicationHelper`) instead of in a controller.

Answer (score 179):

Simplest solution I can come up with in 2015 (verified using Rails 4, but should also work using Rails 3)

```
request.url
# => "http://localhost:3000/lists/7/items"
request.path
# => "/lists/7/items"
```

Comment: And if you want the id in the view: <%= request.path_parameters[:id] %>

Comment: This is awesome! Use this in a partial form to redirect to the current page with new params.
`<form action="<%= request.path %>">`

Answer (score 21):

You can do this

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/your/path"
```

It works for me in rails 3.1.0.rc4

Comment: This returns a hash which is the params hash. Any way to actually get the route object? With the name and then other attributes?

Answer (score 11):

In rails 3 you can access the Rack::Mount::RouteSet object via the Rails.application.routes object, then call recognize on it directly

```
route, match, params = Rails.application.routes.set.recognize(controller.request)
```

that gets the first (best) match, the following block form loops over the matching routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.set.recognize(controller.request) do |r, m, p|
  ... do something here ...
end
```

once you have the route, you can get the route name via route.name. If you need to get the route name for a particular URL, not the current request path, then you'll need to mock up a fake request object to pass down to rack, check out ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path to see how they're doing it.

Comment: Error: `undefined method 'recognize' for #<Journey::Routes:0x007f893dcfa648>`

Answer (score 9):

Based on @AmNaN suggestion (more details):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 def current_controller?(names)
  names.include?(params[:controller]) unless params[:controller].blank? || false
 end

 helper_method :current_controller?

end
```

Now you can call it e.g. in a navigation layout for marking list items as active:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="<%= current_controller?('items') ? 'active' : '' %>">
    <%= link_to user_items_path(current_user) do %>
      <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="<%= current_controller?('users') ? 'active' : '' %>">
    <%= link_to users_path do %>
      <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="<%= current_controller?('alerts') ? 'active' : '' %>">
    <%= link_to alerts_path do %>
      <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For the `users` and `alerts` routes, `current_page?` would be enough:

```
 current_page?(users_path)
 current_page?(alerts_path)
```

But with nested routes and request for all actions of a controller (comparable with `items`), `current_controller?` was the better method for me:

```
 resources :users do 
  resources :items
 end
```

The first menu entry is that way active for the following routes:

```
   /users/x/items        #index
   /users/x/items/x      #show
   /users/x/items/new    #new
   /users/x/items/x/edit #edit
```

Answer (score 7):

Or, more elegantly:  `request.path_info`

Source:
[Request Rack Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request)

Answer (score 6):

Should you also need the **parameters**:

```
current_fullpath = request.env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH']
# If you are browsing http://example.com/my/test/path?param_n=N 
# then current_fullpath will point to "/my/test/path?param_n=N"
```

And remember you can always call `<%= debug request.env %>` in a view to see all the available options.

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you mean the URI:

```
class BankController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :pre_process 

  def index
    # do something
  end

  private
    def pre_process
      logger.debug("The URL" + request.url)
    end
end
```

As per your comment below, if you need the name of the controller, you can simply do this:

```
  private
    def pre_process
      self.controller_name        #  Will return "order"
      self.controller_class_name  # Will return "OrderController"
    end
```

Comment: yes I did that, but I hoped in a better way. What I need is to know which controller has been called, but I have pretty complicated nested resources.. request.path_parameters('controller') doesn't seem to work properly to me.

Comment: No need for `self.` in `self.controller_name` and `self.controller_class_name`

Answer (score 4):

**request.url**

request.path #to get path except the base url

Answer (score 2):

You can see all routes via rake:routes (this might help you).

Comment: I prefer to open a new tab with an invalid path, and see all the path/routes from the browser, since they're prettier that way.

But I don't think this helps get the current route.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
def active_action?(controller)
   'active' if controller.remove('/') == controller_name
end
```

Now, you can use like this:

```
<%= link_to users_path, class: "some-class #{active_action? users_path}" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that the the approved answer, `request.env['PATH_INFO']`, works for getting the base URL, but this does not always contain the full path if you have nested routes. You can use `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']` to get the full path and then see if it matches a given route:

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].match?(my_cool_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `request.env['REQUEST_URI']` to see the full requested URI..  it will output something like below

```
http://localhost:3000/client/1/users/1?name=test
```