# Rails 3 Check if sign in on all routes that match regex?

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Say I have a whole bunch of routes that I only want to be accessible to a signed in user.  I can put in a check in each of the controller methods that says something along the lines of

```
if signed_in?
    #do stuff here
else
    redirect_to root_path
```

I think I can also use a `before_filter` in a controller to reduce the number of times I need to rewrite that (though I'm not super familiar with the syntax offhand).  However, I would ideally like to just have it written in one place that all routes that match a certain regex need to go through this check, e.g. all routes that are of the form `www.mysite.com/admin/...` need this validation check.  Is there any way to do this so I only have to write this check once and not duplicate code across my controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a post that shows how to get the current URL inside of a controller: [How can I find out the current route in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203892/how-can-i-find-out-the-current-route-in-rails)

Now you can write a method inside of `ApplicationController` which checks if the URL begins with `/admin` and validates whether the user is signed in. Call that method in a `before_filter` of the `ApplicationController`. Now this method will be called before every request, but since you check the regular expression first, it will not have any impact on pages that do not start with `/admin`.

It would probably look similar to this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_login_if_admin_route

  def check_login_if_admin_route
    current_uri = request.env['PATH_INFO']
    if !current_uri.start_with?('/admin')
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```